# How to print multiple pages in datagridview using c#?(my data from datagridview is directly connect to sql server.)

Tags: c#, datagridview

**As of the moment this is my printing code. which if there are more rows I can't print the other rows.

```
private void pictureBox4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1094,645);
    this.SetDesktopLocation(300,200);
    dataGridView1.Size = new Size(264, 498);
    label11.Visible = true;
    panel1.Show();
    pictureBox1.Show();
    pictureBox2.Show();
    pictureBox3.Hide();
    pictureBox3.Location = new Point(1015,145);
    pictureBox4.Hide();
    pictureBox4.Location = new Point(1015,202);
}

private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    printPreviewDialog2.ShowDialog();
}

//printing
private void printDocument2_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    printDocument2.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    int heigth = dataGridView1.Height;
    dataGridView1.Height = dataGridView1.RowCount * dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height * 2;
    bmp = new Bitmap(this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height);
    dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height));
    dataGridView1.Height = heigth;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: What issues have you encountered so far printing multiple pages?

Comment: I haven't try multiple pages yet I can't figure it out. Since my data are from directly from sqlserver. most of the codes i read in other sites they are using database set which is different from mine.

Comment: You need to write if statement to check condition if next page is needed than -> e.HasMorePages = true; else e.HasMorePages = false; and it will print everything